# UIView with a UIImageView inside larger

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a UIView with a UIImageView inside larger. Is there a way to hide what lies beyond the size of the view?

```
CGRect baseFrame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 80);
UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:baseFrame];
[self.view addSubview:baseView];
[baseView release];


UIImageView *baseBg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 335)];
[baseBg setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"baseView.png"]]];
[baseView addSubview: baseBg];
[baseBg release];
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UIView.clipsToBounds = YES
```

[UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)